# SharePoint 2016 - Password reset of active directory user account - easy way

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, active-directory

I have SharePoint 2016 environment where i have two set of users,

1. users  with company domain - logging in using enterprise login  (
   say User A )
2. users logging in via an internal - windows active
   directory in a separate server  ( say User B )

Usually, we used to add the user B in our active directory and share their credentials, once they logged in they will change their own password. Now i need to provide an option to for them to reset their password on a SharePOint page itself on their first login.

Please suggest me an easy way to achieve this functionality ? i'd like to use any JavaScript, JQuery solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JavaScript as an end-to-end solution as it cannot interface with LDAP; you will need to develop a good portion of this in C# in order to work with the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.

*However*, SharePoint is not the appropriate tool for this from a security perspective. I would look at purchasing a Self-Service Password Reset tool that is designed for your use-case.

Another note of caution, Microsoft has declared [System.Web.UI.WebControls.PasswordRecovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery?view=netframework-4.8) to be insecure and should not be used. You can see this noted in the [November 2020 PU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-november-10-2020-a64429a3-5876-64e0-7010-4843c2904efd) for SharePoint 2019, 2016, and 2013.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please share any sample c# project files with which i can develop and use it for my sharepoint site.